# Can't run MongoDB 7.0.2 on Windows 10

Tags: mongodb, windows

I can't run MongoDB 7.0.2 service on Windows 10 after clean install; I get

```
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly
```

mongod.log

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.838+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.840+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":21},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.842+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.846+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.849+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.849+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.850+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23316,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Trying to start Windows service","attr":{"serviceName":"MongoDB"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.853+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":4880,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/7.0/data","architecture":"64-bit","host":"qwe"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.853+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.853+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"7.0.2","gitVersion":"02b3c655e1302209ef046da6ba3ef6749dd0b62a","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.853+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19045)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.853+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\7.0\\bin\\mongod.cfg","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"service":true,"storage":{"dbPath":"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\7.0\\data"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\7.0\\log\\mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.855+05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22271,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Detected unclean shutdown - Lock file is not empty","attr":{"lockFile":"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\7.0\\data\\mongod.lock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.856+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/7.0/data","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.857+05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22302,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:33.857+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=1535M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:35.257+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":1400}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:35.257+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:35.300+05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:35.301+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"admin.system.version","uuidDisposition":"provided","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"4beee4dd-1ab8-4105-a874-bf0b082db034"}},"options":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"4beee4dd-1ab8-4105-a874-bf0b082db034"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:35.517+05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23134,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unhandled exception","attr":{"exceptionString":"0xC000001D","addressString":"0x00007FF65F43769C"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:35.518+05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23136,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"*** stack trace for unhandled exception:"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31380,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"BACKTRACE","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"7FF65F43769C","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/immer/dist/immer/detail/hamts/node.hpp","line":883,"s":"immer::detail::hamts::node<std::pair<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection> >,immer::map<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection>,mongo::HashImprover<mongo::UUID::Hash,mongo::UUID>,std::equal_to<mongo::UUID>,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::hash_key,immer::map<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection>,mongo::HashImprover<mongo::UUID::Hash,mongo::UUID>,std::equal_to<mongo::UUID>,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::equal_key,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::copy_inner_insert_value","s+":"2C"},{"a":"7FF65F44051D","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/immer/dist/immer/detail/hamts/champ.hpp","line":615,"s":"immer::detail::hamts::champ<std::pair<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection> >,immer::map<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection>,mongo::HashImprover<mongo::UUID::Hash,mongo::UUID>,std::equal_to<mongo::UUID>,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::hash_key,immer::map<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection>,mongo::HashImprover<mongo::UUID::Hash,mongo::UUID>,std::equal_to<mongo::UUID>,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::equal_key,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::do_add","s+":"39D"},{"a":"7FF65F454C3F","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/immer/dist/immer/map.hpp","line":400,"s":"immer::map<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection>,mongo::HashImprover<mongo::UUID::Hash,mongo::UUID>,std::equal_to<mongo::UUID>,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::set","s+":"BF"},{"a":"7FF65F4320E4","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/collection_catalog.cpp","line":2104,"s":"mongo::CollectionCatalog::_registerCollection","s+":"304"},{"a":"7FF65F453695","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/collection_catalog.cpp","line":2080,"s":"mongo::CollectionCatalog::registerCollectionTwoPhase","s+":"65"},{"a":"7FF65F419236","module":"mongod.exe","file":"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.31.31103/include/functional","line":834,"s":"std::_Func_impl_no_alloc<``mongo::UncommittedCatalogUpdates::_createCollection'::`5'::<lambda_1>::operator()'::`2'::<lambda_2>,void,mongo::CollectionCatalog &>::_Do_call","s+":"56"},{"a":"7FF65F455DB7","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/collection_catalog.cpp","line":694,"s":"mongo::CollectionCatalog::write","s+":"67"},{"a":"7FF65F418D46","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/uncommitted_catalog_updates.cpp","line":128,"s":"`mongo::UncommittedCatalogUpdates::_createCollection'::`5'::<lambda_1>::operator()","s+":"296"},{"a":"7FF6601621CB","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/recovery_unit.cpp","line":74,"s":"mongo::RecoveryUnit::runPreCommitHooks","s+":"4B"},{"a":"7FF660160CC4","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/write_unit_of_work.cpp","line":142,"s":"mongo::WriteUnitOfWork::commit","s+":"94"},{"a":"7FF65E233893","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/repl/storage_interface_impl.cpp","line":472,"s":"`mongo::repl::StorageInterfaceImpl::createCollection'::`2'::<lambda_1>::operator()","s+":"233"},{"a":"7FF65E22FA00","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/concurrency/exception_util.h","line":160,"s":"mongo::writeConflictRetry<`mongo::repl::StorageInterfaceImpl::createCollection'::`2'::<lambda_1> >","s+":"B0"},{"a":"7FF65E2378C5","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/repl/storage_interface_impl.cpp","line":450,"s":"mongo::repl::StorageInterfaceImpl::createCollection","s+":"C5"},{"a":"7FF65EDEEE62","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/commands/feature_compatibility_version.cpp","line":456,"s":"mongo::FeatureCompatibilityVersion::setIfCleanStartup","s+":"2B2"},{"a":"7FF65E1BEF8C","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/startup_recovery.cpp","line":622,"s":"mongo::startup_recovery::repairAndRecoverDatabases","s+":"CC"},{"a":"7FF65E1A55A9","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":560,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::_initAndListen","s+":"CA9"},{"a":"7FF65E1A7D9E","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":984,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::initAndListen","s+":"1E"},{"a":"7FF65EB71773","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/ntservice.cpp","line":601,"s":"mongo::ntservice::initService","s+":"53"},{"a":"7FF84377DFD8","module":"sechost.dll","s":"WaitServiceState","s+":"328"},{"a":"7FF844547614","module":"KERNEL32.DLL","s":"BaseThreadInitThunk","s+":"14"}]}},"tags":[]}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65F43769C","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/immer/dist/immer/detail/hamts/node.hpp","line":883,"s":"immer::detail::hamts::node<std::pair<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection> >,immer::map<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection>,mongo::HashImprover<mongo::UUID::Hash,mongo::UUID>,std::equal_to<mongo::UUID>,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::hash_key,immer::map<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection>,mongo::HashImprover<mongo::UUID::Hash,mongo::UUID>,std::equal_to<mongo::UUID>,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::equal_key,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::copy_inner_insert_value","s+":"2C"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65F44051D","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/immer/dist/immer/detail/hamts/champ.hpp","line":615,"s":"immer::detail::hamts::champ<std::pair<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection> >,immer::map<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection>,mongo::HashImprover<mongo::UUID::Hash,mongo::UUID>,std::equal_to<mongo::UUID>,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::hash_key,immer::map<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection>,mongo::HashImprover<mongo::UUID::Hash,mongo::UUID>,std::equal_to<mongo::UUID>,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::equal_key,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::do_add","s+":"39D"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65F454C3F","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/immer/dist/immer/map.hpp","line":400,"s":"immer::map<mongo::UUID,std::shared_ptr<mongo::Collection>,mongo::HashImprover<mongo::UUID::Hash,mongo::UUID>,std::equal_to<mongo::UUID>,immer::memory_policy<immer::heap_policy<immer::cpp_heap>,immer::refcount_policy,void,immer::no_transience_policy,1,1>,5>::set","s+":"BF"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65F4320E4","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/collection_catalog.cpp","line":2104,"s":"mongo::CollectionCatalog::_registerCollection","s+":"304"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65F453695","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/collection_catalog.cpp","line":2080,"s":"mongo::CollectionCatalog::registerCollectionTwoPhase","s+":"65"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65F419236","module":"mongod.exe","file":"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.31.31103/include/functional","line":834,"s":"std::_Func_impl_no_alloc<``mongo::UncommittedCatalogUpdates::_createCollection'::`5'::<lambda_1>::operator()'::`2'::<lambda_2>,void,mongo::CollectionCatalog &>::_Do_call","s+":"56"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65F455DB7","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/collection_catalog.cpp","line":694,"s":"mongo::CollectionCatalog::write","s+":"67"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65F418D46","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/uncommitted_catalog_updates.cpp","line":128,"s":"`mongo::UncommittedCatalogUpdates::_createCollection'::`5'::<lambda_1>::operator()","s+":"296"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6601621CB","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/recovery_unit.cpp","line":74,"s":"mongo::RecoveryUnit::runPreCommitHooks","s+":"4B"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF660160CC4","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/write_unit_of_work.cpp","line":142,"s":"mongo::WriteUnitOfWork::commit","s+":"94"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65E233893","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/repl/storage_interface_impl.cpp","line":472,"s":"`mongo::repl::StorageInterfaceImpl::createCollection'::`2'::<lambda_1>::operator()","s+":"233"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.664+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65E22FA00","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/concurrency/exception_util.h","line":160,"s":"mongo::writeConflictRetry<`mongo::repl::StorageInterfaceImpl::createCollection'::`2'::<lambda_1> >","s+":"B0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.665+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65E2378C5","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/repl/storage_interface_impl.cpp","line":450,"s":"mongo::repl::StorageInterfaceImpl::createCollection","s+":"C5"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.665+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65EDEEE62","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/commands/feature_compatibility_version.cpp","line":456,"s":"mongo::FeatureCompatibilityVersion::setIfCleanStartup","s+":"2B2"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.665+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65E1BEF8C","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/startup_recovery.cpp","line":622,"s":"mongo::startup_recovery::repairAndRecoverDatabases","s+":"CC"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.665+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65E1A55A9","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":560,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::_initAndListen","s+":"CA9"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.665+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65E1A7D9E","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":984,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::initAndListen","s+":"1E"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.665+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF65EB71773","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/util/ntservice.cpp","line":601,"s":"mongo::ntservice::initService","s+":"53"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.665+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF84377DFD8","module":"sechost.dll","s":"WaitServiceState","s+":"328"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.665+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF844547614","module":"KERNEL32.DLL","s":"BaseThreadInitThunk","s+":"14"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.665+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23132,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Writing minidump diagnostic file","attr":{"dumpName":"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\7.0\\bin\\mongod.2023-10-17T09-54-40.mdmp"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-17T14:54:40.789+05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23137,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"*** immediate exit due to unhandled exception"}
```

Comment: Feels like the type of problem that you should reach out to the vendor about

Comment: Is the service already running, do you try to start it twice?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit no, it's not running. I have installed 6.0.11 version now and it works well

Comment: If I remember correctly, 0xC000001D is "illegal instruction", you might check the system/cpu requirements on the mongodb website

Comment: @Joe it seems like you are right. thank you. only strange thing that 6.0 works.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/administration/production-notes/#platform-support), MongoDB 7.0 is not supported on Windows 10.